# Using multiple assignment to update linked list pointers

Tags: python

I'm working on this problem (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/reverse-a-linked-list/problem) and I've come across an issue I noticed before, but still haven't resolved.

Here's my code to start with:

```
def reverse(llist):
    cur = llist
    pre = None
    while cur:
        temp = cur.next
        cur.next = pre
        pre = cur
        cur = temp
    return pre
```

In Python, there's a technique called multiple assignment that can be used, like in this snippet:

```
temp = cur.next
cur.next = pre
pre = cur
cur = temp
```

can be rewritten as

```
cur.next, pre, cur = pre, cur, cur.next
```

From my understanding, multiple assignment first forms a tuple from the values on the right side of the equals sign, then assigns them in order to the variables on the left side.

But why do these three patterns not work?

```
cur, cur.next, pre = cur.next, pre, cur
cur, pre, cur.next = cur.next, cur, pre
pre, cur, cur.next = cur, cur.next, pre
```

These three patterns would result in the following errors:

```
cur, cur.next, pre = cur.next, pre, cur
         ^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

I can't explain or understand why 'cur' would become a NoneType.
I believe that if 'cur' were None, it would be caught in the while loop's condition check.

The following is the complete code (from HackerRank)

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

class SinglyLinkedListNode:
    def __init__(self, node_data):
        self.data = node_data
        self.next = None

class SinglyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def insert_node(self, node_data):
        node = SinglyLinkedListNode(node_data)
        if not self.head:
            self.head = node
        else:
            self.tail.next = node
        self.tail = node

def print_singly_linked_list(node, sep, fptr):
    while node:
        fptr.write(str(node.data))
        node = node.next
        if node:
            fptr.write(sep)
#
# Complete the 'reverse' function below.
#
# The function is expected to return an INTEGER_SINGLY_LINKED_LIST.
# The function accepts INTEGER_SINGLY_LINKED_LIST llist as parameter.
#
# For your reference:
#
# SinglyLinkedListNode:
#     int data
#     SinglyLinkedListNode next

def reverse(llist):
    cur = llist
    pre = None
    while cur:
        # temp = cur.next
        # cur.next = pre
        # pre = cur
        # cur = temp

        # Work
        # cur.next, pre, cur = pre, cur, cur.next
        # cur.next, cur, pre = pre, cur.next, cur 
        # pre, cur.next, cur = cur, pre, cur.next

        # Error
        # cur, cur.next, pre = cur.next, pre, cur
        # cur, pre, cur.next = cur.next, cur, pre
        # pre, cur, cur.next = cur, cur.next, pre

    return pre

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    tests = int(input())
    for tests_itr in range(tests):
        llist_count = int(input())
        llist = SinglyLinkedList()
        for _ in range(llist_count):
            llist_item = int(input())
            llist.insert_node(llist_item)
        llist1 = reverse(llist.head)
        print_singly_linked_list(llist1, ' ', fptr)
        fptr.write('\n')
    fptr.close()
```

Sample Input

```
3
5
16
12
4
2
5
3
7
3
9
5
5
1
18
3
13
```

Sample Output

```
5
2
4
12
16
9
3
7
13
3
18
1
5
```

Comment: Please explain why you feel the three patterns ‘do not work’. What is your observation? (Please update the question accordingly.) Additionally, have a good think about what `cur.next` *is* and what it’s doing at a lower level. (Update the question with these observations.) **Hint:** `type(cur)` might be of use.

Comment: @s3dev Thanks for the reminder, I have edited the article and added the reason

Comment: Looks like the name `cur` doesn't get assigned before `cur.next` as an assignment target is evaluated.

Comment: Please provide enough code for us to reproduce the issue ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've understood the problem and I'll leave my thoughts here for future reference by anyone with the same question.
Thank you very much to everyone who came to watch or comment.

Schematic diagram:

```
pre     cur
 |       |
None - Node1 - Node2
                 |
             cur.next
```

```
cur.next, cur, pre = pre, cur.next, cur

temp = (pre, cur.next, cur)
cur.next = temp[0] # Node1.next = pre = None
cur = temp[1] # cur = cur.next = Node2 (because it's a value not a link)
pre = temp[2] # pre = cur = Node1
```

```
cur, cur.next, pre = cur.next, pre, cur

temp = (cur.next, pre, cur)
cur = temp[0] # cur = cur.next = Node2
cur.next = temp[1] # Node2.next = pre = None (Because cur is updated to Node2, if Node2 is None, the Error described in the article will occur.)
pre = temp[2] # pre = cur = Node2
```